# File URI scheme won't open folder

Tags: firefox, microsoft-outlook, filesystems, uri

URI links to folders (in `file://blahblahblah` format) simply aren't working for us in some cases.

Users with Windows, using Active Directory.

URIs opened from the following don't work:

- Firefox
- Links in received emails in MS Outlook (regardless of default browser)

However, the same URIs work in:

- Internet Explorer
- Directly entering URI in Start > Run

There are no errors when URI doesn't open; it simply doesn't open.

---

UPDATE: I am aware there might be a known issue with Firefox. But why in Outlook? What can be causing this?

---

UPDATE 2: Actual links are more like `file:///\\%5c%5c\hostname\path` and `file://hostname/path/`.

Comment: Is "file://blahblahblah" a realistic example of a URL that isn't working?

Comment: @Kenster uh... no. :)

Comment: Well, "file://blahblahblah" isn't a valid file: URL. Maybe you could provide a more realistic example. The exact letters aren't important, but the number and position of the slashes can be.

Comment: @Kenser Updated question. Note that URIs do open in IE and from Run.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox

---

This is a browser security measure as it prevents a user from unwittingly accessing the local file system., in firefox e.g. you can turn it on using

```
user_pref("capability.policy.policynames", "localfilelinks");
user_pref("capability.policy.localfilelinks.sites", "http://yourServer1.companyname.com http://yourServer2.companyname.com");
user_pref("capability.policy.localfilelinks.checkloaduri.enabled", "allAccess");
```

Outlook

---

To add a hyperlink to network file / folder take a look at [Outlook: Creating a hyperlink to a network file](http://cybertext.wordpress.com/2008/12/01/outlook-creating-a-hyperlink-to-a-network-file/)

Comment: What about Outlook? Is that a security measure as well?

Comment: No, take a look how to do it: http://cybertext.wordpress.com/2008/12/01/outlook-creating-a-hyperlink-to-a-network-file/